# Remove All Whitespace but keep all &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, html

How can I remove all whitespace from a div, except `&nbsp;`?

I have tried to use `.trim()` and `.replace(/\s/g, '');` but that removes  `&nbsp;` too.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem in your question. Preferably via a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the space character in your regex instead of `\s` joker.

```js
document.getElementById('result').innerText = document.getElementById('test').innerText.replace(/ /g, '');
```

```html
<div id="test"> Test And&nbsp; Final Test </div>
<div id="result"> Test And&nbsp; Final Test </div>
```

Comment: Wow! i tried to remove last char of a div with:  replace(/(\s+)?.$/, '') it works, but ignore &nbsp; - how can i remove any last char and also &nbsp; ?

Comment: Your goal is not very clear. Now, you want to remove only last spaces of a string, right ? Using /(\s+)$/ regexp will target all last spaces as char or as html entity.